Cannot use 'insertAdjacentHTML' inside a JSON fetch
So I'm creating this script that goes trough a list of ahref links,

checks if they're a github.com link,
fetches a JSON file based on that github link,
and prepends a <strong>2024-10-20</strong> element with the date key from this JSON file.

The problem is, if I console.log(jsonResponse.date) the JSON response, inside of this fetch, the date appears to be outputted, as a string.
But when I try to use it on a insertAdjacentHTML I get an error.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'insertAdjacentHTML')
at getSuggestions (scripts.js:78:17)

Which points to this line: gitLinks[i].insertAdjacentHTML

I've also tried to push the responses to and empty array jsonDates, but it doesn't work either. The array returns empty.
If I move the gitLinks[i].insertAdjacentHTML outside the fetch, it prepends normally.
I can't figure out what the problem is.


const gitLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.page-content li a[href*="https://github.com/"]');

let jsonDates = [];

for (var i = 0; i < gitLinks.length; i++) {
  const getGithubHref = gitLinks[i].getAttribute('href');

  const githubDomain = 'https://github.com/';
  const githubRepository = getGithubHref.slice(getGithubHref.indexOf(githubDomain) + githubDomain.length);
  const githubJSON = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/' + githubRepository + '/master/metadata.json';

  const getDates = async() => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amiyasahu/q2a-breadcrumbs/master/metadata.json');
      if (response.ok) {
        let jsonResponse = await response.json();
        console.log(jsonResponse.date);

        gitLinks[i].insertAdjacentHTML(
          'beforebegin',
          `<strong>${jsonResponse.date}</strong>`,
        );

        jsonDates.push(jsonResponse.date);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
  getDates();
}

console.log(jsonDates);
<div class="page-content">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="//github.com/NoahY/q2a-badges">Badges Plugin</a>. Provides user badges which recognize users' activities and achievements.</li>
    <li><a href="//github.com/amiyasahu/q2a-breadcrumbs">Breadcrumbs Widget</a>. Displays navigational breadcrumbs showing the path to the currently viewed page.</li>
    <li><a href="//github.com/arjunsuresh/q2a-betterpoints">Better Points</a>. Extends the default point system by adding points for giving comments, receiving comment upvotes/downvotes.</li>
  </ul>
</div>




The issue is that the i in gitLinks[i] has been updated by the for(var i=0; by the time the async fires.  Confirm by adding console.log(i) directly before the insertAdjacentHTML line

I told you this would be closed as a duplicate when it was in staging :p

Yeah @JaromandaX also pointed that out while my question was pending for review. Thanks a lot everybody!
I'd like to upvote your comments, but I can't :\
